# Need help creating advanced context menu command in Windows 7 (x64)

Tags: windows-7, networking, command-line, context-menu

I found out about [ForceBindIP](http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/) and I really love it, so much that I am using it regularly enough to where spamming the same command prompt over and over again is getting painful.

I'm on a 64-bit of Windows 7 Home Premium. What I want to do is add a right-click context menu item so that when I browse items in Windows Explorer, or on my desktop, I can automate a ForceBindIP command (through the prompt).

I am permanently connected to two networks: one over ethernet, and one over wireless. My ethernet network takes priority. What I want to do is add a "Run through wireless network" context menu item, that will send the item through this command:

```
ForceBindIP {5F657824-9E3B-46E5-C21E-F52585R6457E} "[path to right-clicked file here]"
```

It will need to run that command in **C:\Windows\SysWOW64**.

I've no experience at all playing with the Windows registry or writing batch files, anything of that sort. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I may be missing something because I’m can’t see where the advanced part is, so let me know if there’s a complication that I missed.

Copy the following into a text file and save it as something like `ForceBindIP-ShellExt.reg`. Run it and merge it like any other registry file, then right-click on an executable file and you should have the context-menu entry ready to go.

```
REGEDIT

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\ForceBindIP]
@="Run through wireless network"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\ForceBindIP\command]
@="C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ForceBindIP {5F657824-9E3B-46E5-C21E-F52585R6457E} \"%l\""
```

Comment: Thanks. After posing this question, I tried this more and eventually managed to get just about where you are. My next question is about cascading menus.

I'd like to create a "Run through" menu with 2 options, "Wireless" and "LAN". How could I go about doing that?

Comment: Nope; you can’t do that with the registry. To make cascading menus, you need to either write a shell-extension (a DLL) or use a third-party shell-extension like [MMM](http://hace-software.com/mmm.shtml) that lets you add custom entires.

Comment: Hey again, actually. I try running an application through that context menu item and receive: http://puu.sh/EdZn

Any ideas? I have UAC off.

Comment: Nevermind! Changed %windir% to the absolute path now and it's fine, thanks again!

Comment: Maybe it's a stupid question but...why you add this:

{5F657824-9E3B-46E5-C21E-F52585R6457E}

in the path to the ForceBindIP executable?

Comment: @Torres, that is the GUID associated with his NIC. You’ll need to [replace it](http://superuser.com/questions/686163/where-can-i-find-my-nics-guid-for-use-with-forcebindip) with the GUID associated with your own NIC.

Answer (score -1):

Try the `-i` switch:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\Open using ForceBindIp\command]
@="c:\\windows\\syswow64\\forcebindip.exe -i  {5F657824-9E3B-46E5-C21E-F52585R6457E} \"%l\""
```

Comment: You haven't explained how this helps.