# Regedit Issues

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need help creating advanced context menu command in Windows 7 (x64)](https://superuser.com/questions/442442/need-help-creating-advanced-context-menu-command-in-windows-7-x64)

I am trying to do exactly this [Synetech's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/442442/need-help-creating-advanced-context-menu-command-in-windows-7-x64), on the exact same system however after it says that the key has been added to the registery it has not.

Comment: ... ya its a duplicate im trying to do the exact same thing and im wondering if someone can tell me how to manually enter this instead because the way described isn't working

Comment: the best way to ask is to ask as a comment (which I understand you don't have enough rep to do so just yet), but asking the same question isn't the way to go about this.

Comment: I was trying to ask in a comment or private message synetech (which i would prefer doing) however i cannot comment or private message so there is no other way of contacting synetech that i know of