# Where can I find my NIC’s GUID (for use with ForceBindIP)?

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-adapter, guid

I’m trying to create a context-menu item to run ForceBindIP. I saw a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/442442/need-help-creating-advanced-context-menu-command-in-windows-7-x64) that discusses doing this, but I don’t know how to find the GUID for my network interface.

Where can I find it?

Answer (score 14):

You find the GUIDs of your NICs manually [through the registry](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/145314-how-to-get-the-active-network-name-or-guid/), or you can find them a little more easily from the command-prompt:

1. Run the *Service* snap-in (`services.msc`)
2. Start the `Wired AutoConfig` and `WLAN AutoConfig` services if they are not already running
3. Open a command-prompt
4. Run the following command:

   ```
   netsh lan show interfaces
   netsh wlan show interfaces
   ```

The first command will list wired network adapters, along with their GUIDs, and the second will display wireless NICs.