# Windows File Sharing does not work with firewall disabled

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares, file-sharing

I have a Windows 7 computer which I am trying to use for sharing files over my home network (but not using a homegroup).

Here is what I have tried so far.

- Network Discovery and File and Print Sharing is **enabled** for both Private and Public Networks.
- Windows Firewall is **disabled**.
- I can access files on other computers properly.
- The System process is listening on Port 0.0.0.0:445.
- The user password is 8 characters or more.
- The 4 services involved are all running.
- IPv6 is enabled, but I don't know if that matters for regular file sharing.

From the computer in question,

- Accessing `\\localhost` works properly.
- Accessing `\\computer-name` only shows the share list but I can't open them.
- Accessing `\\ip-address` doesn't even show the list of shares.

From other computers, I am unable to see anything and I am never prompted for a password. It times out after 30-60 seconds.

Is there something in Event Viewer which I can use to further determine what the problem is?

Reinstalling Windows is definitely NOT an option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot connect to Windows share via local network IP address, but can by localhost](https://superuser.com/questions/1240213/cannot-connect-to-windows-share-via-local-network-ip-address-but-can-by-localho)