# Windows 11 PC can't connect to local file share by IP, but can by hostname?

Tags: windows-11

I'm running into this issue with a win11 enterprise laptop that's unable to connect to the file shares on my home network by IP through windows explorer.  If I connect to \denpc\share it's fine, but if I try \192.168.1.101\share, the connection fails.  This seems very strange.  Here's my ipconfig for the relevant adapter:

```
Ethernet adapter DockEthernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Lenovo USB Ethernet
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 08-3A-88-5E-CA-3C
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.158(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : March 25, 2022 5:12:27 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : March 27, 2022 8:59:33 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Here's some things I've tried so far:

- Pinging 192.168.1.101 works
- Tracert to 192.168.1.101 works directly
- ping denpc works and resolves the IP
- RDP to 192.168.1.101 works

The fact that I can RDP to the IP but not access file shares seems strange.  Nothing is firewalled off, network discovery is enabled, and netbios over TCP is enabled everywhere.  I did check out [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1240213/cannot-connect-to-windows-share-via-local-network-ip-address-but-can-by-localho) solution, but that didn't seem to help (all the registry settings were already there).  Is there something that might be windows 11 specific that could be blocking this?

Note-probably should have shared this first, but this is the error Explorer pops:

[image]

Comment: No issue here with connecting Windows 11 to Windows 11 by IP address.  Open cmd.exe and enter NET USE Z:\\192.168.1.101\foldershare   press enter. What numerical error do you get?

Comment: Tried that-got "System error 67 has occurred.The network name cannot be found."

Comment: Actually, you pointed me in the right direction.  Command syntax was actually wrong though: "NET USE Z: \\192.168.1.101\foldershare" came back with "System error 1272 has occurred. You can't access this shared folder because your organization's security policies block unauthenticated guest access. These policies help protect your PC from unsafe or malicious devices on the network."

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out-John's comment above about trying to map a network drive was on the right track.  Running "NET USE Z: \192.168.1.101\foldershare" (with the space) came back with:

```
System error 1272 has occurred.

You can't access this shared folder because your organization's security policies block unauthenticated guest access. These policies help protect your PC from unsafe or malicious devices on the network.
```

Searching on that error suggested a few links, including [this one](https://forums.unraid.net/topic/89452-windows-issues-with-unraid/page/8/#comment-878167) that pointed to a policy to block insecure/anonymous guest logons.  What's odd is that I don't think there's a domain policy to set this (since a win10 machine that was joined to the same domain never had this issue), and the local policy was set to disabled, and the description read "If you enable this policy setting or if you do not configure this policy setting, the SMB client will allow insecure guest logons.".  That implies to me that "not configured" should have worked.  Changed it to Enabled and things started behaving, so I'll just write it off as a quirk of GPO and move on.  Thanks for the nudge in the right direction.